# Handling Hunspell suggestions with special characters

Tags: c++, ascii, hunspell

I've integrated [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net) in an unmanaged C++ app on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010.

I've got spell checking and suggestions working for English, but now I'm trying to get things working for Spanish and hitting some snags.  Whenever I get suggestions for Spanish the suggestions with accent characters are not translating properly to `std::wstring` objects.

Here is an example of a suggestion that comes back from the `Hunspell->suggest` method:

[image: Hunspell->suggest(...) result]

Here is the code I'm using to translate that `std::string` to a `std::wstring`

```
std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& str)
{
    std::wstring convertedString;
    int requiredSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);
    if(requiredSize > 0)
    {
        std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(requiredSize);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, &buffer[0], requiredSize);
        convertedString.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
    }

    return convertedString;
}
```

And after I run that through I get this, with the funky character on the end.

[image: After conversion to wstring]

Can anyone help me figure out what could be going on with the conversion here?  I have a guess that it's related to the negative char returned from hunspell, but don't know how I can convert that to something for the `std::wstring` conversion code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the output of Hunspell is ASCII with code page `28591` (ISO 8859-1 Latin 1; Western European (ISO)) which I found by looking at the Hunspell default settings for the unix command line utility.

Changing the `CP_UTF8` to `28591` worked for me.

```
// Updated code page to 28591 from CP_UTF8
std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& str)
{
    std::wstring convertedString;
    int requiredSize = MultiByteToWideChar(28591, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);
    if(requiredSize > 0)
    {
        std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(requiredSize);
        MultiByteToWideChar(28591, 0, str.c_str(), -1, &buffer[0], requiredSize);
        convertedString.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
    }

    return convertedString;
}
```

Here is a [list of code pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN that helped me find the correct code page integer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the output of Hunspell is ASCII with code page 852.
Use 852 instead of CP_UTF8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

Or configure Hunspell to return UTF8.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know what I find

Comment: It turns out it's not 852, but you're link did lead me to the right answer.  The default code page was 28591.